# Jenkins on Openshift unable to service request due to maintenance downtime

Tags: maven, jenkins, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I have a **jenkins** server on **Openshift**, The server **goes down** during  the build even 
after upgrading my plan to the bronze plan and using a large gear.

Each time I run a jenkins build on Openshift I get this message in the middle of the build:

```
The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.
```

And then the build disapear from the build history.

Is there a way to know why jenkins **goes down** during the build ? which *logs* should I check ?

I set the `Builder size` to `large` and the `Builder type` to `jbossas-7`, is there a better configuration to use to be able to finish the build?

Is there a way to set my maven repository in the slave so I can save some of my disk quota ?

In advance,Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/continuous-integration.html#how-jenkins-build-works) you can find more information on how Jenkins builds work on OpenShift. The best place to check the logs would be the Jenkins web interface, if the build record is available there. If not, I would try [tailing](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/log-files.html#tailing-logs) the temporary created builder app for some clues or [contact OpenShift support](https://developers.openshift.com/help.html) for assistance.

Comment: Is there a way I can ssh into the bldr created during the build and verify the amount resources allocated to the build ?